# Magento2: how can I resize the image used in gallery in the product page.

Tags: magento2, product, gallery, fotorama-slider

In magento2 product page, the image gallery is rendered by fotorama.

The image size is exactly the same as the one upload to product.

Is it possible to resize all the image to the same size/ratio?

Thanks

Comment: You can set image sizes for product page and other pages in etc/view.xml

Comment: Do you have any updates of this?

Answer (score 1):

Override gallery.phtml in your theme -> `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml`

```
  <?php
        foreach ($block->getGalleryImages() as $image) { ?>

                <?php if ($block->isMainImage($image)): ?>

                    <img src="<?php echo $image->getData('large_image_url') ?>">
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ((!$block->isMainImage($image))): ?>

                    <img src="<?php echo $image->getData('large_image_url') ?>">
                <?php endif; ?>

        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your theme > `app/design/frontend/package/theme-name/etc/view.xml`
Inside `<media>` node you can define different image sizes:

```
<images module="Magento_Catalog">
    <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
        <width>700</width>
        <height>560</height>
    </image>
</images>
```

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: belfort1, if xml has the configuration, it should work at least. But for him images are not resizing at all. They remain same as uploaded image.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way to resize your image :-

```
$_imageHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image'); productImage = $_imageHelper->init($_product, $image)->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(400)->getUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image" type="Sample\Code\Model\Product\Image" />
</config>
```

add this in Sample\Code\Model\Product\Image

```
 namespace Sample\Code\Model\Product;

    /**
     * Class Image
     * @package Sample\Code\Model\Product
     */
    class Image extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image
    {
        protected function _construct () {
// set the quality of the image raging form 0 to 100
            $this->_quality = 100;
            parent::_construct();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it will work fine if any quires let me know